# GTA San Andreas screen issue running on wine

Tags: wine

When I launch `gta_sa.exe` the screen goes blank and comes back with the screen resolution messed up. The desktop is HUGE.

With the game also fully responsive I can only see the top right of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your wine configuration then click on graphics and click emulate virtual desktop then run the game and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Well fist you would have to tell wine that you want it to launch a program or game  `wine gamename`

Or to install a program that wouldn't launch you have to use the saved file name for example:

```
wine C:\Program Files\progeamnme\gta_sa.exe
```